# Styling loading state before Angular2 app starts not working?

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-styleguide

In my index.html, I want to show users a loading state before Angular2 app starts/ bootstraps.

```
<my-app>
    <div class="sk-cubes">
      <div class="sk-cube1"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube2"></div>
    </div>
  </my-app>
```

I am trying to give styles in a style sheet named loading-state.css and including it in index.html but somehow it is not taking styles from this file. However, I am getting expected behaviour when giving styles in  tag in header or inline styles. Did I miss out on something?

Comment: Do you use `angular-cli`?

Comment: No, I don't use angular-cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume **`loading-state.css`** reference has been given in `head` tag of **`index.html`** page

In **`myapp`** component, set **`ViewEncapsulation`** to **`none`**.

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'myapp',

  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None   // <<<=====here

})
class MyAppComponent {

}
```